# Convex function of an Expectation of a Random Variable Intuition

Tags: logarithms, convex-analysis, expected-value, parameter-estimation

In working with estimating the parameters for a log-normal distribution, I initially made the mistake in parameterising the distribution using the log of the mean observation value, as opposed to taking the mean of the log-observation values. i.e. I realised: 
$$
E[\log(X)] \ne \log(E[X])
$$
I understand the above inequality mathematically, and in its relation to Jenson's inequality for convex functions. But is there an intuitive meaning to the RHS term, in distinction to the LHS or otherwise, or is it mathematically/statistically uninformative?

Comment: If you are old or old-fashioned enough to dislike multiplication, you could say of uncorrelated random variables that $\log(\mathbb E[XY]) = \log(\mathbb E[X]) +\log(\mathbb E[Y])$

Comment: So if $\mathbb{E} [X]=\frac{1}{n}\Sigma x_n $, then $\log(\mathbb{E}[X])=-\log(n)+\log(\Sigma x_n)$, is this what you're referring to? Again, I can see mathematically they are not equal, but am asking if there is any intuition behind the term $\log(\mathbb{E}[X])$

Comment: No - I was combining (a) the expectation of the product of two uncorrelated random variables is the product of their individual expectations and (b) the logarithm of the product of two numbers is the sum of their individual logarithms.  It is not particularly special.